# Zsh prompt with directory and virtual environment

Tags: terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am having trouble finding a succinct answer to this. I am using Oh My Zsh, and right now using the default theme, robbyrussell.

I would like my prompt to have 2 components:

1. The current directory, plus one level up
2. If I am using a virtual environment (like anaconda), have the name of the active environment in parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the way to do it, you can customize it as per your needs

```sh
# Helper method to add background and foreground colors
prompt_segment () {
    local bg fg
    [[ -n $1 ]] && bg="%K{$1}"  || bg="%k"
    [[ -n $2 ]] && fg="%F{$2}"  || fg="%f"
    if [[ $CURRENT_BG != 'NONE' && $1 != $CURRENT_BG ]]
    then
        echo -n " %{$bg%F{$CURRENT_BG}%}$SEGMENT_SEPARATOR%{$fg%} "
    else
        echo -n "%{$bg%}%{$fg%} "
    fi
    CURRENT_BG=$1
    [[ -n $3 ]] && echo -n $3
}

prompt_virtualenv () {
    # Check if we are in a virtual environment
    # if we are then VIRTUAL_ENV variable will be set
    local virtualenv_path="$VIRTUAL_ENV"
    if [[ -n $virtualenv_path && -n $VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT ]]
    then
        # We are in virtual env so show just the project name
        prompt_segment blue black "(`basename $virtualenv_path`)"
    fi
}

prompt_directory() {
    # Show the current directory
    prompt_segment red blue $PWD
}

build_my_zsh_prompt() { 
    # Call all the prompt functions to build the actual prompt
    prompt_virtualenv
    prompt_directory
    prompt_segment black white ""
}

# Assign the PROMPT variable with the function, so bash call it everytime
# Single quotes are important here, else you will get a fixed PROMPT
# Without single quotes, the function will be called once and evaluated value 
# will be assigned
PROMPT='$(build_my_zsh_prompt)'
```

`PROMPT` variable is used by `zsh` shell to determine what needs to be displayed as the prompt. When we set `PROMPT=$(build_my_zsh_prompt)`, we are asking shell to call our function `build_my_zsh_prompt`.

This function in turn (ideally) should call different function which create individual parts of prompt. Now let's look at `prompt_directory`

```sh
prompt_segment black red $PWD"
```

The `prompt_segment` is a helper function to echo some text with background and the foreground color

First parameter `black` is the background and second parameter `red` is the foreground color in this case. Next we show what text needs to be given for this prompt.

All of this needs to be added to your `~/.zshrc` file at the very end

Comment: Could you please add comments so I understand what's going on here? Also, what file do I put this in?

Comment: @Adam_G, updated the answer with more details. Please check now

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try in the morning!

Comment: This raises the following error: `prompt_parent_directory:1: command not found: prompt_segment
prompt_directory:1: command not found: prompt_segment
build_my_zsh_prompt:4: command not found: prompt_segment` which makes sense. What should prompt_segment() say?

Comment: Ok, so this raises another issue. I can't get a prompt in my terminal, just the error above. How can I edit the file?

Comment: Open `sh` or `bash` directly and then you can edit the `~/.zshrc`

Comment: How would I do that without a Terminal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198056/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-adam-g).